# Is this integral solvable in terms of standard functions or gamma functions or hypergeometric functions?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I have been doing some physics (in the context of spectral functions if anyone is iterested) and now my problem boils down to calculating an integral of the following type

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^2(B+Cx^{p})-D} dx, $$
where $B \in \mathbb{R}, C, D > 0$ and $-1\leq p \leq 0$. To me it looked like normal techniques wouldn't work so I tried complex analysis but to use that I need to know the pole structure of the integrand. However, I couldn't solve the equation $denominator = 0$.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: $D >0$ and $1\leq p \leq 0$ (stange notation for the second)

Comment: I changed it to $-1$ haha

Comment: The integrand behaves like $1/(Bx)$ as $x \to \infty$, so the improper integral diverges (unless $B=0$).

Comment: Is there also not a way to make sense of this in terms of distributions?